# Iterate over columns with a fixed row

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

is it possible to iterate over columns with a fixed row/cell and to create a new column with the values. For example I want to create a column like that:

```
F1=A1
F2=B1
F3=C1
F4=D1
```

and so on

Comment: Hi Namal. How are the values selected? EG if a cell is equal to x THEN

Comment: I have data in several columns, for instans I want to find the max of each column and add the value in a row in a new column F1 = MAX(A1:A100000), F2 = MAX(B1:B100000), F3 = MAX(C1:C100000)...Is it possible to automate it if you have a lot of columns? The only way to do it I know is to copy the function for each cell and replace the column char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the formula

```
=MAX(OFFSET($A$1:$A$10000;0;ROW()-1))
```

in cell F1 and stretch it down.

The expression `ROW()-1` will take the value 0 for F1, 1 for F2, 2 for F3, and so on, and the `OFFSET()` function uses these values ​​to move from the range A1:A10000 to 0, 1, 2, and so on columns.

[image: Three different offices]

Comment: I tried it out in OpenOffice and Exel, but for both I get ```#NAME?``` as result in every cell of F1 to F(number of my columns)

Comment: I also tried this formula in different offices.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your answer was correct the first time. I failed to realize that I have to rename the functions to my language settings. It is ```=MAX(BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN($A$1:$A$10000;0;ZEILE()-1))```
in German. Thank you very much.